# creating an object of a class in python

Tags: python

I created a class in python, why am I getting this error?

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, name, brand):
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand

    def printDetails(self):
        return 'Name: ', self.name, '\nBrand: ', self.brand

    c1 = Car('A4', 'Audi')
```

`NameError: name 'Car' is not defined`

Answer (score 6):

You must define `c1` *outside*  of `Car`. Fix your indention:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, name, brand):
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand

    def printDetails(self):
        return 'Name: ', self.name, '\nBrand: ', self.brand

c1 = Car('A4', 'Audi')
```

Hint: Implement [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) or [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) instead of `printDetails`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, name, brand):
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand

    def printDetails(self):
        return 'Name: ', self.name, '\nBrand: ', self.brand

c1 = Car('A4', 'Audi')
```